# Mathematica for dynamics and controls

Tags: dynamic, symbolic, control-systems

I am new to Mathematica and want it to use for dynamic and control systems. To begin with, I would want to be limited to symbolic computation for linear and nonlinear control systems - including frequency domain analysis. I know quite a lot about MATLAB, so based upon that, any suggestions on how can I get started with it would be helpful. The things that I am looking for are:

1. Videos that show analysis of a few systems.
2. Syntax for mathematica for use of control systems.
3. Interaction in the frequency domain? (like do we have direct commands or do we have to use laplace transformations to actually mathematically model it).

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Look up: www.wolfram.com, Support&Learning, Control Systems. Have fun

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: I'm afraid your question may be considered too broad for Mma.SE so it may even be closed.  If you can, please [edit] to add details that may narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered instead of just commented about. Don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your future [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) are welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/10397). You can still [edit] your question.